# Multidimensional Array - Match by odd key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find the difference of 2 multidimensional arrays. I am attempting to solve this with a modified recursive array difference function.

If I have the following array setup:

```
$array1 = array(
  0 => array(
      'Age' => '1004',
      'Name' => 'Jack'
  ),
1 => array (
    'Age' => '1005',
    'Name' => 'John'
)
);

$array2 = array(
0 => array(
    'Age_In_Days' => '1004',
    'Name' => 'Jack'
),
1=> array(
'Transaction_Reference' => '1005',
'Name' => 'Jack'
)
);
```

I am trying to match the arrays however the keys are not the same. I want to return the difference between the two multidimensional arrays where

```
 $array1[$i]['Age'] == $array2[$i]['Age_In_Days'];
```

I want to keep the original array structure if the above condition holds true so the output I am looking for is:

```
 $diff = array (1 => array (
    'Age' => '1005',
    'Name' => 'John'
));
```

However I am having issues with how to modify the recursive function to achieve this. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Excuse me, 1=> array ( 'Transaction_reference' etc... was a mistake. Ignore that. I have removed it in my source file.

Comment: Edit your question if the code above is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through first array and compare values with second array. Then follows your condition. If condition is true then push this unique value to third array. Values in third array are now diff between first and second array.

```
$diff = [];
foreach ($array1 as $value1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $value2) {
        if ($value1['Age'] !== $value2['Age_In_Days']) {
            array_push($diff, $value1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer? Without any commentary, it makes it harder to see how this may answer the OP's question.